# how to cocos2dx read file on android

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have a text file "test.txt" under the Resources, and a function "parseSth(char* str)" in the "util.cpp" to read the "test.txt" do something. 
However, if I use like this parseSth("text.txt"), the ios and android all cannot find the file. And use parseSth(CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath("text.txt")) will work fine on ios, but cannot find the path.
Why?  How I can do?

Comment: i have saved this problem

Comment: I faced the sample problem. So i wrote all my file IO stuff in ANDROID and used JNI to bridge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your file is embedded into APK file on Android and thus doesn't have a path to it per-se.
Use the following function to extract data from the file (it automatically handles apk/sd card differences).

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->getDataFromFile(filename)
```